# To check if Inactive date and inactive status greater than 10 , 12 months then trigger email individually

Tags: sharepoint-online

Below are my flow steps and its not working as expected for below scenarios

Condition 1)when inactive date is greater than 10 months and SRstatus is equal to inactive. trigger email

Condition 2)If inactive date is greater than 12 months and SRstatus is equal to inactive trigger email

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on conditions you provided, it can be merged into as long as the inactive date is greater than 10 months and SRstatus is equal to inactive, then trigger email.

Try to set condition as following pictures show.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do we need to set 2 conditions in the same flow? please confirm

Comment: "When inactive date is greater than 10 months" and "If inactive date is greater than 12 months" can be combined into a single condition - inactive date is greater than 10 months.

Comment: Thanks. But your screenshots have 2 condition steps and how to combine this in single step and please clarify.

Comment: These two screenshots are to show two formulas separately in the first condition. Inactive date and SRstatus need to each have a condition, link with And, and tick the boxes in front of both conditions.